# Making instance field as cache key?

Tags: java, spring, spring-cache

I m using `org.springframework.cache.annotation.Cacheable` for method level cache

```
public class Customer {

private Long id;

@Cacheable("customer",key="this.id")
public CustomerAddress findCustomerAddress() {...}

}
```

I want to cache the customer object with key as id. But i don't have id as method parameter. I have it as instance field ?

Comment: Is each `Customer` managed by Spring to begin with? A more usual approach is to use `@Cacheable` in your service/DAO layer, not directly on the domain objects (which usually wouldn't be managed by Spring at all). In other words: you'd solve this problem by moving `findCustomerAddress` to the service layer and sending the user's ID as its input parameter.

Comment: Yes customer is spring managed bean. This code is in service layer only . I just gave example what I want to achieve

Comment: Does CustomerAddress.id is the property you want to use as cache key?

Answer (score 0):

You can't easily do that and the code above has two smells IMO:

- You're trying to cache an `address` in a `customer` cache
- The object you're trying to cache does not seem to have its own identity. You'd then rather cache the `Customer` (which has one) rather than a sub-component

You already had great comments to your original question and I'd suggest you to review your current design so that the object you cache has its own identity. If you can't or won't, there's always a way.

```
@Cacheable(cacheNames = "customer", keyGenerator="customerKeyGenerator")
public CustomerAddress findCustomerAddress() {...}

}
```

And then in some `@Configuration` class

```
@Bean
public KeyGenerator customerKeyGenerator() {

}
```

The API of [`KeyGenerator`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/interceptor/KeyGenerator.html) is simple enough. You could for instance check that the target instance is a `Customer` and then retrieve the id value.